# 3 displays with AMD Radeon HD 6900 series; 2 DVI 1 HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, amd-radeon

I have two monitors plugged into the two available DVI slots plus a 40' HDTV plugged into the one HDMI slot. However when I try to extend my desktop onto the TV it automatically disables my secondary monitor. I know that my card is supposed to support up to 6 displays. What do I need to get them all working?

**Edit:**

To support more than two monitors for this card you need an ACTIVE adapter to mini DisplayPort (in my case HDMI to mDP). If it's not active it won't work. I ordered one online and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only two monitors can be conneted with DVI or HDMI, other ones require DisplayPort connections. [Eyefinity FAQ](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/faqs.aspx) will give you more details on that. You can use adapters to connect your displays if they don't support DisplayPort.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my graphics card actually has two mDP ports on it. Will those work? (with HDMI->mdP or DVI->mDP)

Comment: Yes, those will be fine. mDP is 100% compatible with DisplayPort, just smaller.

Comment: I just went to the electronics store and bought a HDMI->mDP adapter. My computer is telling me the same thing: to extend I need to disable one of my displays.....

Comment: Look for something Eyefinity-related in driver settings. You'll have to choose the setup you'd like to have. Driver will join all screens into one big screen that will be presented to the OS.

Comment: I think I found the problem... I need an "active" adapter. I took the other one back and ordered the "right" one online. Eyefinity setting wasn't even giving me the option to create a group of more than 2. Hopefully new adapter will fix.